# .git folder in modules/extentions

Tags: git, drupal, yii

I have a main git repository for a `Yii` project and a `Drupal` project.  Whenever I download a extension or module I delete the `.git` folder from that module/extension because I don't think there is a need of adding the module's git history to my main git repository.

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You are doing right ;)

Comment: Did you explore using subtree or submodules? Things will work fine right now, but you may have nightmares if you try upgrading the modules/extensions later in the project lifecycle.

Comment: @ansh0l that is why I am confused. The way I upgrade modules is I download the module and then replace manually. Do you keep your .git folder for every module and later just do a git pull/checkout on each module to get the latest?  Won't this increase the size of your main repo since you will have every modules history committed too?